# Problems with useState (replicating array with render) - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to load some data with a State (that's working), but I want to fill an array because I bring those data partionated.

Here is my code:

```
const PokemonList = (props) => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const pokemonList = useSelector(state => state.PokemonList);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        FetchData({page: page})}, []);
    
    const FetchData = (page) => {
        dispatch(GetPokemonList(page));}

    React.useEffect(()=> {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", isScrolling);
            return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", isScrolling);}, [pokemonList]);

    function isScrolling(){
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop!==document.documentElement.offsetHeight){
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("scrolling down");
            const newPage = page + 1;
            const maxPage = Math.round(pokemonList.count / 20);
            if (page < maxPage) {
                setPage(page + 1);
                FetchData(page);
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, I'm loading 20 datas with a API, then I show those 20 datas. If I want more 20, I can show only the newest 20 (because the state update, it not accumulate). I'm trying to create a array to fill those datas, but everytime that I fill the array, it duplicate my data because the render... I tried to built a:

```
pokemonList.data.map(el => el.data.push(pokemons))
```

it used to work, but it replicates everything :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code (sorry, ReactJS Rookie) but to accumulate the data to previous state you have to do something like:

`setState([...state, newState])` which means, first you have to spread the previous state, then add the new state that is fetched from API

Comment: But the question is that I dont want to accmumulate haha.. it's accumulating everytime it's render, but I just want the new values :/

Comment: @Override_GER guess you just have to use the ‘setState(newValue)’ and will set the newest value only